# how to change oracle explain plan for sql query manually

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle sql query and it has access plan attached to it. How can i change the access plan without changing the sql query. I think oracle has database table that store sql id and plan id , updating the plan id to new plan id will force the sql query to use different explain plan.

I am using Oracle 10, In this case i don't want to touch the existing query. I will write another query with hints and get the desired explain plan created. now I will use the new marker for the explain plan and attach it to the original sql id. This is the logic how to do this, but i dont know what all tables need to be updated to achieve this. Step1 : SQLI_D1 -> PLAN_ID1; Step2 : SQL_ID2 -> PLAN_ID2; STep3 : SQL_ID1 - > PLAN_ID2

Comment: Why do you want to do this - because you think Oracle has picked a sub-optimal plan? Does Oracle have all the information it needs to produce a reasonable plan - particularly, are the statistics up to date? Or are you maybe suffering from bind variable peeking, if you're on 10g? (It's less of an issue on 11g). You can provide hints to the optimizer, but that changes the statement, and is often a bit of a hack to hide an underlying issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many answers, since your question is too broad. And you haven't even mentioned the DB version.

You said :

> updating the plan id to new plan id will force the sql query to use
>   different explain plan.

No. The `PLAN_HASH_VALUE` is assigned by Oracle. It is a marker to relate an `EXECUTION PLAN` with the respective `SQL_ID`. If you want to force the `OPTIMIZER` to take a different execution plan of your choice, you could use `HINTS` in your query.

If you have *pinned or preserved the execution plan* for the SQL using `stored outlines` etc., also known as `PLAN STABILITY`, then you need to remove it, so that Oracle would be able to find a proper execution plan in it's next execution. And then, if required, you can stabilize the better plan as you think so.

Comment: I am using Oracle 10, In this case i don't want to touch the existing query. I will write another query with hints and get the desired explain plan created. now I will use the new marker for the  explain plan and attach it to the original sql id. This is the logic how to do this, but i dont know what all tables need to be updated to achieve this. Step1 : SQLI_D1 -> PLAN_ID1; Step2 : SQL_ID2 -> PLAN_ID2; STep3 : SQL_ID1 - > PLAN_ID2

Answer (score 0):

Explain plan depends on its query and also on the statistics. For example oracle won't use an index if there is only one record in the table but it will use the index if there is a lot of records in the table and you extract only few of them. So you need to gather the statistics as much as possible.

But I don't understand your intention to force oracle recalculate the explain plan, Oracle knows how to access your tables based on the statistics you provide. Do not use hints like `INDEX` and other that tell oracle how to access tables. You can give oracle a hint that to tell oracle that you need only top 5 rows, and oracle will return them to you as fast as it can.

Comment: >`oracle won't use an index if there is only one record in the table` .... ***Are you sure?*** I can show you that Oracle will use the index with just one row in the table.

Comment: [Tottaly](http://pastebin.com/2ZM0Srxx)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - it generally won't use an index if its selectivity means it would be more expensive to do a separate index and table fetch. Why do two lots of I/O when you can only use one? A single row is just an extreme example. (I forget the threshold for when it becomes more efficient to hit the index first, but I used to use 10-15% as a rule-of-thumb). zaratustra's demo works with an explicit `gather_schema_stats()` too.

Comment: @Alex, as a ROT, I keep it even lower, ~ 5-10%. But, it depends on a lot of factors. What I was referring to zaratustra's statement is, it cannot be totally the only case. There is no rule-of-thumb about index scan with number of rows in the table.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for clarifying. I used this extreme example to tell OP that oracle knows what to do on its own.

Comment: @zaratustra, [Not Totally](http://pastebin.com/hMfNvMAa)

Comment: @LalitKumarB you forgot about [statistics](http://pastebin.com/s1mVttBL). Oracle will use an index if you haven't gathered any statistics.

Comment: Even with stats gathered, and even with another column being fetched, it's still using the index (index range scan => table access by index rowid), which isn't what I'd expect either. And with a unique or non-unique index. Interesting.

Comment: It might be version specific. I am on 12.1.0.1. And I don't see FTS. That's why I said that it can't be Totally true, it just depends.

Comment: I use 11.2. Show me your case with gathered stats. I know that if a table has lob field and you want to extract this field, oracle will use lob segments. Also if you want to count a field that is stored in an index oracle also will use the index. I know that there are more examples.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c718f/1). With no filter it does a FTS; with a filter it doesn't. But this has all drifted off rather a long way; think 'it depends' is usually a safe answer when talking about the optimizer... it seems to like to surprise *8-)

Comment: [stats gathered and it uses an index](http://pastebin.com/3x51PxHz)

Comment: @LalitKumarB are you sure your user is scott?

Comment: @zaratustra, [Yes](http://pastebin.com/txrzng53)